# Combine list recursively in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have made this in Prolog

```
contains(psu,[fan,cable,transformer]).
contains(screen,[panel,cable,psu]).

contains(fan,[plastic,cable,copper]).
contains(cable,[copper,plastic]).
contains(transformer,[wire,core]).
contains(wire,[copper,plastic]).
contains(panel,[glass,polarizingfilter,liquidcrystals]).
```

And I want to make a question `componentsOf(X)` where it returns all components and subcomponents of `X` in a list like

```
componentsOf(psu)
[fan,cable,transformer,plastic,copper,wire,core]
```

I tried making a list by appending it everytime and using `sort/2` in the end but didn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library **ordset** of SWI-Prolog is your friend :

```
componentsOf(Obj, Components) :-
    components_([Obj], Comps),
    ord_subtract(Comps, [Obj], Components).

components_(Lst, Out) :-
    % change setof with findall because setof fails when L is empty
    findall(X, (member(Y, Lst), contains(Y, X)), L),
    flatten([Lst | L], FlatL),
    list_to_ord_set(FlatL, SetL),
    ord_intersection(Lst, SetL, Intersection, Difference),
    (   Difference = []
        ->  Out = Intersection
    ;   components_(Difference, Out1),
        ord_union(Out1, SetL, Out)).
```

Example :

```
 ?- componentsOf(psu, Out).
Out = [cable, copper, core, fan, plastic, transformer, wire].
```

**EDIT** I change **setof** with **findall** :

```
?- componentsOf(screen, X).
X = [cable, copper, core, fan, glass, liquidcrystals, panel, plastic, polarizingfilter|...].
```

Comment: Thanks,this produces the desired result,but only works for the psu and fan, screen for example returns false

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findall/3` in this way:

```
solve(L1,L2,L3):-
    findall(X,contains(X,_),L1),
    findall(X,contains(_,X),L2),
    findall([X,Y],contains(X,Y),L3).
```

Query:

```
?- solve(L1,L2,L3).
L1 = [psu, screen, fan, cable, transformer, wire, panel],
L2 = [[fan, cable, transformer], [panel, cable, psu], [plastic, cable, copper], [copper, plastic], [wire, core], [copper, plastic], [glass, polarizingfilter, liquidcrystals]],
L3 = [[psu, [fan, cable, transformer]], [screen, [panel, cable, psu]], [fan, [plastic, cable, copper]], [cable, [copper, plastic]], [transformer, [wire, core]], [wire, [copper, plastic]], [panel, [glass, polarizingfilter, liquidcrystals]]]
```

In `L1` you get all the components, in `L2` you get all the subcomponents and in `L3` you get a list with components and subcomponents.

Comment: Yeah but i want to find them by item, For example (screen)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/minimal%20BOM.swinb) you can see a working solution, example of fixpoint iteration.

```
components(SoFar, Cs) :-
    setof(P, C^L^
        ((member(C,SoFar),contains(C,L),member(P,L))
         ;member(P,SoFar)), Ts),
    ( Ts = SoFar -> Cs = Ts ; components(Ts, Cs) ).

part_components(P, Cs) :-
    % corrected to exclude P from Cs
    % components([P], Cs).
    contains(P, Ps),
    components(Ps, Cs).
```

Compact, but not very efficient... OTOH, it produces readable (well, sorted) answers:

```
?- part_components(screen,R).
R = [cable, copper, core, fan, glass, liquidcrystals, panel, plastic, polarizingfilter, psu, transformer, wire]
```